# R equivalent of Java map

Tags: r, rjava

I would like to pass a key/value pair from my R code to a java function.
My java function has argument `Map<String,String >` .

How can I write R function which calls my Java function and pass values to map ??

**EDIT :**

```
config <- list(Portname="PORT.H.2",MktValue="8000000",WtScheme="Closed")
createPortfolio<-function(config)
{
   m <- .jnew("java/util/HashMap")
   for( key in names(config)){
     m$put( key, config[key])

}
m
```

getting

```
  Error in FUN(X[[2L]], ...) : 
  Sorry, parameter type `NA' is ambiguous or not supported.
```

Comment: Which library, are you using, rJava?

Comment: @rlegendi any idea on how to run this using rjava ?

Comment: Nobody listening my thread :(

Comment: My answer should work (see [page 13 in the package docs](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rJava/rJava.pdf)). Isn't one of the key or config elements NA?

Answer (score 1):

How about trying something like this?

```
m <- .jnew("java/util/HashMap")
m$put( "key", "value" )
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant

```
for (key in names(config)) m$put(key, config[[key]])
```

since you want to pass string as value to `put` and not a list.

(Consider asking on the rJava mailing list stats-rosuda-devel to get a more prompt answer)

Answer (score 0):

For people, like myself, who had this issue and don't have access to the Java code, it seems to be possible to make a HashMap, and cast it to a Map, like this:

```
m <- .jnew("java/util/HashMap")
m$put( "key", "value" )
map <- .jcast(m, "java/util/Map")
```